# How do you read project properties set on the Gradle CLI in the settings.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, groovy, properties, settings

We're trying to add an override mechanism for our plugin repositories, something like:

```
maven {
    url = gradle.hasProperty("overrideUrl") ? gradle.overrideUrl : "https://default/server"
}
```

It would be nice if we could use the same value that users would specify as a project property.

I've tried the following and it looks like the `rootProject` properties are not set in the scope of the settings.gradle file:

```
maven {
    url = rootProject.hasProperty("overrideUrl") ? rootProject.overrideUrl : "https://default/server"
}
```

The goal is to have both the build.gradle and the settings.gradle impacted by something like:

```
./gradlew -PoverrideUrl=https://custom/server
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha! I found it. The `rootProject` does not have it's ExtraPropertiesExtension added in the settings.gradle file, but we can access this via the `Settings` object in the `settings.gradle`:

```
maven {
    url = settings.hasProperty("overrideUrl") ? settings.overrideUrl : "https://default/server"
}
```

The same value can be referenced in the `build.gradle` with:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = project.hasProperty("overrideUrl") ? project.overrideUrl : "https://default/server"
    }
}
```

Both can be controlled via:

```
./gradlew -PoverrideUrl="https://custom/server"
```